# Windows Server 2016 Joined to Windows Server 2003 Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-controller

Trying to research an answer but can't seem to find out: Can a Windows Server 2016 server be joined to a domain with 2003 Domain Controllers?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: [*"...functional levels do not affect which operating systems you can run on workstations and member servers that are joined to the domain or forest."*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/understanding-active-directory-functional-levels(v=ws.10).aspx) -- That said, do you know that 2003 is EOL since 14 July 2015?

Comment: Ok thanks. Yes, aware that 2003 is long dead - but one step at a time here :)

Comment: For me that "one step" concern would be "How to I migrate from 2003 DCs/DFL/FFL" not "Can I add 2016 members to 2003 DCs/DFL/FFL". Diff'rent Strokes. :)